# I breathe when I dance

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does it mean when someone says “I breathe when I dance”? I was trying to conversation with someone when I told then that I loved to dance. This was their response to that

Comment: They must mean they really like it, come alive, breathe freely. In English, we frequenty use such figurative language and invent it as we go along. But it is not an established idiom.

Comment: Got is. Thanks @YosefBaskin for the reply!